# Relation between sets of vertices in a graph

Tags: graphs

Suppose I have a graph with vertices of three colors - black, gray, and white. I want to compare the connectivity between sets of vertices to make claims like - the black set is more related to the white set than the gray set, and so on. How are such claims measured? Are there standard metrics or methods for that case?

Comment: Are you familiar with the notion of *conductance of a cut* in graphs ? Usually, we measure the conductance between `S` and `V\S` where S is a subset of vertices, but you could adapt the formula to measure the conductance between distinct subsets.